# Smooth transition between display none and flex jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a little menu on a side, with *HTML*, *CSS* and *Javascript*, and I want it to fade in when the user scrolled under the header. This was working perfectly well until I tried to improve the responsive part of my website design.

I changed the menu from `display: block;` to `display: flex;` since screen size can change and I want all the lines of my menu to always fill the whole menu. I just changed my code a little bit in the *.js* script like so:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 600) {
 $('#menu').css('display','flex');
  } else {
 $('#menu').css('display','none');
  }
}
```

The problem is that the transition is not smooth anymore. I used `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` methods from jQuery to do so with `display: block;`, but I don't have the same fading effect with the direct *.css* method.

I already tried those things:

- Add a `transition: 1s;` in my `#menu` id in *CSS*. **Didn't fix it.**

```css
#menu {
  z-index : 3;
  position : fixed;
  display: none;
  flex-direction : column;
  justify-content : space-around;
  width : 15%;
  height : 50%;
  right : 1.5%;
  top : 20%;
  font-size : 24px;
  transition : 3s;
}
```

- Keep the `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` methods, and add the .css changes after those. **Didn't fix it**.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 600) {
    $('#menu').fadeIn();
    $('#menu').css('display','flex');
  } else {
    $('#menu').fadeOut();
  }
}
```

I don't know what else I could try. I searched for various solutions, but most of them are talking about the `.css` method itself, not the fading effect I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tested,but you try to 'flag' that makes (document).scroll run once.
because your code, case y =700 then do  $(document).scroll run, case y=701, case y=702???

```
var flag=false;
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 600 && flag==false) {
    $('#menu').fadeIn();
    $('#menu').css('display','flex');
     flag=true;
  } else if(y<=600 && flag==true) {
     flag=false;
    $('#menu').fadeOut();
  }
}
```